# Stack Overflow account not logging out?

Tags: support, logout

I used company system to login to my Stack Overflow account, now it's not logging out. It says:

> Oops! Something Bad Happened!
>
> We apologize for any inconvenience, but an unexpected error occurred
>   while you were browsing our site.
>
> It’s not you, it’s us. This is our fault.

I don't want to leave w/o log-out. How to log out my account from this system?

I tried logout and close browser but still, my account is logged in.

I am using `Mozilla Firefox 48.0` on Ubuntu. It finally logged out after multiple tries; after logout when I did try to login again I got this:

> Suspicious request
>
> *Sorry, your request could not be completed because it looked suspicious. If you meant to perform an action on Stack Overflow,
>   please return to the previous page and try again.*

Comment: Time for the obligatory 'Eagles, Hotel California' comment?

Comment: What browser are you using? Can you tell us what steps you are taking to log out?

Comment: It could by your company network is applying some kind of network filtering or has browser plugins that interfere. In any case, you can force a logout by clearing all history for Stackexchange.com with [How can I clear a single site from the cache in Firefox?](//superuser.com/q/173210)

Comment: thanks a bunch @MartijnPieters it worked.